# Is it possible to inherit javadoc from another class/method without type inheritance?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

Say I have a bunch of annotations under the same domain where some properties of them are common.

```
@Color
@interface Black {
    /**
     * The density of the color in range 0-255. If a non valid value is given, an
     * exception will be thrown.
     * 
     * @return the density of the color
     */
    int density();
}

@Color
@interface Red {

    //inherit javadoc from Black#density
    int density();
}
```

The comment in `@Red` says what I want to do.

Is there something better than @see tag? (`@see Black#density()`)

Maybe there is a maven tool (plugin) that can make it happen?

Comment: If your types all have `int density()`, why not let them extend the same `Colour` interface?

Comment: @JFabianMeier You mean use an interface instead of annotations?